# In which cases should I not call user_access() in a form submission handler?

Tags: 7, forms

Reading the code for [`user_register_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_register_form/7), I see the following comment:

> Pass access information to the submit handler. Running an access check inside the submit function interferes with form processing and breaks `hook_form_alter()`.

The code right after that comment is the following, where `$admin` is set to `user_access('administer users')`.

```
  $form['administer_users'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $admin,
  );
```

Looking at [`comment_form_submit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_form_submit/7), I notice that `user_access()` is being used.

```
  if (user_access('post comments') && (user_access('administer comments') || $node->comment == COMMENT_NODE_OPEN)) {
    // Save the anonymous user information to a cookie for reuse.
    if (user_is_anonymous()) {
      user_cookie_save(array_intersect_key($form_state['values'], array_flip(array('name', 'mail', 'homepage'))));
    }

    // …
  }
```

Is there any difference between the first case, and the last one? If there isn't any difference, what approach should I use in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little detective work to find when that `user_register_form()` code was committed and then traced the [corresponding issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/687586).

From comment [#21](https://www.drupal.org/node/687586#comment-5780858) there:

> The problem is that you can't form_alter out the admin behavior without rewriting the submit handler from scratch.

So I guess the approach you use just depends on whether you want to allow your access checks to be altered by other modules without them having to override your submit handler.